# Add Tapgesture on UILable across application

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a huge application with 100 + labels (Default UILabel - no custom class for my label) in multiple storyboards

Now I want to add tapGesture for all labels (UILabel) for user to allow to copy the label content to clipboard.

Im new to swift so I was thinking to add it in extension of UILabel but it doesnt allow me to add stored properties. If i add this in function in extension then I might have to call this function where ever my label is used.

Is there a way to add gestureRecognizer so that it applies to all labels inherited from UILabel class. Please advice

Comment: Subclass UILabel and use that everywhere.

Comment: Can u please gimme reference how I can do that. I've been trying but no luck

Comment: If I subclass then I have to change all storyboards labels of type created subclass correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.